# Target Audience in a to view only active documents

Tags: 2016

I have a document library that I setup 2 views.  One of the views I only want active documents to show.  Can you assist with this?

Answer (score 2):

Target Audiencing refers to setting view permissions on specific web parts. If, for whatever reason, you have two views available on one page, you would place the page in edit mode, scroll to the far right of the screen, and click "edit properties" on the web part. From there, you will see a setting titled "Target Audience" where you can specify which group(s) will see web part A, and you can do the same thing for web part B.

If you're talking about applying a filter to one of your 2 views, you would want to go into your list/library settings and select your view in order to modify the view settings. In the filter section, you should select the field that you're using to determine what is active vs inactive and set the filter to use the active value (e.g., "Active", "True", etc.). In the following example, you might change "Title" to "Active", "contains" to "is equal to", and "SharePoint" to "True":

[image: filter sample]

Source for image: http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2011/08/11/understanding-filters-in-sharepoint-list-views-aspx/

Answer (score 2):

What you'll need to do first is define when a document is active. So if you haven't already, you should go into the document library and create a column called "Status" with several options or "Active" with a yes/no checkbox.

1. In the library, open the **Library** ribbon and click **Create Column**.
2. Name the column and choose for the type either **Choice** (if multiple statuses) or **Yes/No** checkbox.
3. Click **OK** to create the column.

Once this is done, you need to create a view that filters to show only Active documents:

1. In the library, open the **Library** ribbon and click Create View.
2. Click **Standard View** for your view type.
3. Name your view.
4. Select the relevant columns to show. I would recommend not showing the Status column unless it has multiple values that indicate an active document (if it's a Yes/No option, there is no reason to show it since the view only shows Yeses).
5. Expand the **Filter** option and select **Show items only when the following is true**.
6. Select your column from the dropdown and select **is equal to** in the next dropdown, then enter either **Yes** if you had a Yes/No value for Active or enter one of the values from the Status column that indicates an active document.
7. If you have multiple values that indicate an active document, select the **or** radio button below your selections and repeat step 6 for all additional values.
8. Click **OK** to create your view.